# AngularJS with ui-router and additional state on first request

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am writing an AngularJS Application using ui-router. The states 'home' and 'book' are loaded into the (parent) - ui-view element

My setup for the routes is as following :

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
   $stateProvider
       .state('home', {
           url: '/home',
           templateUrl: '/home2/app'
       })

       .state('book', {
           url: '/book',
           templateUrl: '/book/index'
       })


       .state('book.overview', {
           url: '/overview',
           templateUrl: '/book/overview'
       })

       .state('book.edit', {
         url: '/edit/:bookid',
         templateUrl: '/book/detail',
         controller: 'bookeditcontroller'
       })

      .state('book.create', {
         url: '/create',
         templateUrl: '/book/detail',
         controller: 'bookeditcontroller'
      });

});
```

When the user tiggers the 'book' state (through a href), the template from '/book/index' is loaded and displayed successfully. But on this first request, i also want to load the template from '/book/overview' and displaying it in the child ui-view.

i've already read the topics about the default states under https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-set-up-a-defaultindex-child-state

But this is not exactly the behavior i want. Is there a way to tell ui-router when parent state 'book' is loaded, also load 'book.overview' into its (child) ui-view ?

Thanks for you help!

Comment: i guess opening the child state directly would open parent state as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that you will need

#### [Multiple Named Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views)

This allows us to think in **one state - many views**

State would look like this

```
.state('book', {
       url: '/book',
       views : {
         '' : { templateUrl: '/book/index', },
         '@book': {templateUrl: '/book/overview' },
       }
   })
```

this way, we will place two views into one state.

- The first will be injected into index.html/root `<div ui-view=""></div>`
- The second will be placed inside of the `templateUrl: '/book/index',`

That's how we can play with many views in one *(or even more parent, grand parent...)* state.

*I created a plunker with `layout`, which does show a bit [similar example](http://plnkr.co/edit/I0BJ09BxR7nG9kZDeEIv?p=preview). The code snippet of the state with many views is:*

```
$stateProvider
    .state('index', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
          '@' : {
            templateUrl: 'layout.html',
            controller: 'IndexCtrl'
          },
          'top@index' : { templateUrl: 'tpl.top.html',},
          'left@index' : { templateUrl: 'tpl.left.html',},
          'main@index' : { templateUrl: 'tpl.main.html',},
        },
      })
```

Comment: Great! ;) Enjoy awesome `ui-router`